# Data from OnEventActivityAsync will not change the ConversationState after the first time

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

So I am working on a bot with the Azure Bot Framework that should be able to filters results to users question based on what page they are on. It is able to get from the server to the bot fine and filter the results fine as well. The problem is that after the first time the filters is set, if the user changes the page the new filter that is being passed to the bot is not being saved in the Conversation State. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169079/how-to-save-and-later-retrieve-data-acquired-from-the-oneventactivityasync-method) to my previous question on the subject for reference, but the necessary information will be provided below.

Constructor and SaveChanges

```
public class DialogBot<T> : ActivityHandler where T : Dialog
{
    protected readonly Dialog _dialog;
    protected readonly BotState _conversationState;
    protected readonly BotState _userState;
    protected readonly ILogger _logger;
    IStatePropertyAccessor<QnAPrompting.Helpers.FilterHolder> convoAccess;
    //FilterHolder convoData;

    String temp;

    public DialogBot(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState, T dialog, ILogger<DialogBot<T>> logger)
    {
        _conversationState = conversationState;
        _userState = userState;
        _dialog = dialog;
        _logger = logger;
        temp = "";
        convoAccess = _conversationState.CreateProperty<FilterHolder>("metaNV");
    }

    public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
         await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

         // Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
         await _conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
         await _userState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

OnEventActivityAsync(Updated with suggestion from first answer below):

```
protected override async Task OnEventActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
            string[] paths = { ".", "Helpers", "a.json" };
            string fullPath = Path.Combine(paths);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fullPath, "-->The Filter from the event is: " + turnContext.Activity.Name + "\n");

            var settheFilter = new FilterHolder();
            settheFilter.filter = turnContext.Activity.Name;
            await convoAccess.SetAsync(turnContext, settheFilter, cancellationToken);
            await _conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
}
```

OnMessageActivityAsync:

```
_logger.LogInformation("Running dialog with Message Activity."); 

string[] paths = { ".", "Helpers", "a.json" };
string fullPath = Path.Combine(paths);
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(fullPath, "-->In OnMessage\n");


var settheFilter = await convoAccess.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new FilterHolder());
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(fullPath, "-->The filter is: " + settheFilter.filter + "\n");

turnContext.Activity.Summary = settheFilter.filter;

System.IO.File.AppendAllText(fullPath, "-->The Summary is: " + turnContext.Activity.Summary + "\n");
//--------------------------------
await _dialog.Run(turnContext, _conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState"), cancellationToken);  //meta filter
//-
```

The following is an example of what is happening:

First Time Through(This works Properly):

```
–>The Filter from the event is: king-kingvalue
–>In OnMessage
–>The filter is: king-kingvalue
–>The Summary is: king-kingvalue
```

However, on the second time through I am getting this:

```
–>The Filter from the event is: queen-queenvalue
–>In OnMessage
–>The filter is: king-kingvalue
–>The Summary is: king-kingvalue
```

When I should be getting this:

```
–>The Filter from the event is: queen-queenvalue
–>In OnMessage
–>The filter is: queen-queenvalue
–>The Summary is: queen-queenvalue
```

So again, the problem is that the _conversationState is not being saved the second time through for some reason. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you setting "king-kingvalue" in the `FilterHolder` constructor?

Comment: No I am not, the FilterHolder class just has "public String filter { get; set; }", a getter and setter method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out. The process to save and get the data from the _conversationState works, it was just that when I would switch tabs the event would start a new conversation, not continue the old once as I thought. So while it would get the new queen-queenvalue filter and save it to the new conversation, the old once was still being used and never got the update.

To solve this I ended up storing the first Conversation.Id(A) the user gets from the first tab in a property of the _userState, then setting the new Conversation.Id(B) to the Id of the first conversation. So basically (B) = (A). I will list my code with the relevant changes below. (FYI: UserProfile is just a class I created that holds information)

Constructor:

```
        public DialogBot(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState, T dialog, ILogger<DialogBot<T>> logger)
        {
            _conversationState = conversationState;
            _userState = userState;
            _dialog = dialog;
            _logger = logger;

            //_conversationState = new ConversationState(_myStorage);
            metaAccess = _conversationState.CreateProperty<FilterHolder>("metaNV");
            userProfileAccess = _userState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>("userprofile");
        }
```

OnEventActivityAsync:

```
        protected override async Task OnEventActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            string[] paths = { ".", "Helpers", "a.json" };
            string fullPath = Path.Combine(paths);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fullPath, "-->The Filter from the event is: " + turnContext.Activity.Name + "\n");
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(fullPath, "-->The Conversation in Event is: " + turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id + "\n");
           var userProfile = await userProfileAccess.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserProfile(), cancellationToken);
 if (userProfile.hasFirstConversationId == false)
            {
                userProfile.hasFirstConversationId = true;
                userProfile.conversationId = turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id;
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(fullPath, "-->The UserState userProfileId in Event is the first, it is: " + userProfile.conversationId + "\n");
            }
            else
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(fullPath, "-->The UserState userProfileId in Event is not the first, it is: " + userProfile.conversationId + "\n");
                turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id = userProfile.conversationId;
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(fullPath, "-->The new Conversation in Event is: " + turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id + "\n");
            }
            await userProfileAccess.SetAsync(turnContext, userProfile, cancellationToken);
            await _userState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
            //--Filters
            var settheFilter = await metaAccess.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new FilterHolder(), cancellationToken);
            settheFilter.filter = turnContext.Activity.Name;

            await metaAccess.SetAsync(turnContext, settheFilter, cancellationToken);
            await _conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
```

NOTE: While this solves the question in this post, there is still an error that all users talking to the bot will be put into the same conversation. So if User A is on the Queen Page, and then User B goes to the King Page, Users A's filters will be updated to king-kingvalue, instead of staying queen-queen value. I will post this problem elsewhere, but just thought I should mention it!

Answer (score 0):

You are never calling `SetAsync` so your bot state will never change. You should be doing something like this:

```
protected override async Task OnEventActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IEventActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    string[] paths = { ".", "Helpers", "a.json" };
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(paths);
    File.WriteAllText(fullPath, "-->The Filter from the event is: " + turnContext.Activity.Name + "\n");

    var settheFilter = new FilterHolder();
    settheFilter.filter = turnContext.Activity.Name;
    await convoAccess.SetAsync(turnContext, settheFilter, cancellationToken);
    await _conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext);
}
```

It's unclear how your "metaNV" property ever got set to "king-kingvalue" in the first place, but my suspicion is that you're setting it as some sort of default.

Comment: I have updated my code with your suggestion, but it is still not working. Also, for clarification, the metaNV is just a property I am making in the constructor. It is set the king-kingvalue in the OnEventActivityAsync because it is getting a post from my server whose name is king-kingvalue, and is then setting the filter to that. It is set in the first place because that is always the first page the user loads into. However, if your were to go to a separate page and refresh it, its filter queen-queenvalue would be set to metaNV.